# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^{10}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix and let $x$ and $y$ be two linearly independent vectors. If $Ax = 2y$ and $Ay = x$ how can I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^{10}$?
I noticed that $A^2x = 2x$ and $A^2y = 2y$ but haven't been able to progress further. Any advice/hint is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $A^{10}(x) = A^2(A^2(A^2(A^2(A^2(x))))))$

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you accept one of the answers?

Comment: Oh sure! Sorry I'm a bit new to the site so not very used with all the commands and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the basis $\{x,y\}$ the matrix $A$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 2 &0\end{pmatrix}$. So $A^2=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\ 0 &2\end{pmatrix}$,
so $A^{10}=\begin{pmatrix}32 & 0\\ 0 & 32\end{pmatrix}$. Its eigenvalue is $32$ (double) and its eigenvectors are all non-zero vectors in the span$\{x,y\}$, that is all non-zero vectors in the $2$-dim space.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$A^{10} = (A^2)^5$ which means you can easily calculate $A^{10}x$ and $A^{10}y$.